# Changes to HTML files are not affecting the view in the Browser

Tags: javascript, html, playframework-2.0

So I am currently working on a Play Framework Project. Now I wanted to do some changes to one of my HTML files. But if I, for example change the name of a Button, the change won't happen when I look at it in the browser. It doesn't matter what I change: Background color of some div, some simple text. The changes I make won't show up in the browser.

When I try to change the text of a button with javascript, it doesn't work as well. When I make other changes to the javascript file, like an alert box, it works fine.

I already tried to clear the browser cache and to build the project again.

So what can cause this issue and how can I solve it?

EDIT: So I tried to do the same thing with another project. And when I make changes to the views and refresh the browser it works. Also I get those messages in the play console:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source and 1 Java source to 

    /Users/stefanroth/Desktop/TryAgain/Project Kopie/IDP_Benchmarking-master/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to /Users/stefanroth/Desktop/TryAgain/Project Kopie/IDP_Benchmarking-master/target/scala-2.11/classes...

--- (RELOAD) ---

[info] - application - Shutting down connection pool.
[info] - application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[info] - play.api.db.DefaultDBApi - Database [default] connected at jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/IDP_Benchmarking
OS is = mac os x
[info] - play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
```

I don't get them when I try to do that at my actual Project. So for some reason my project doesn't reload.

Comment: Are you loading the right file? That seems to be the only possibility for this not to work

Comment: Yes I am sure. I work usually in IntelliJ on it. But I tried also to do run in outside the IDE and the same thing happens.

Comment: When I make changes to the view and then refresh the browser, shouldn't the play console tell me that it reloaded it?

Comment: So it depends on the framework that you are using and your build configurations. In some type of configurations your HTMLs need to be compiled before you see those changes. Sorry for not being much of a help here.

Comment: Well the thing is, I am not the first person who works on this project. So I never made changes to the build configurations. That's because I didn't have this issue before. Everything worked as expected. This issue just occurred today to me. For me it just looks like, that the project doesn't update the views anymore. Also I struggle to find to force it to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think most of the framework works on a template method.

So that any changes don't affect easily to its core layout and style type.

I suggest you find its template folder (its MVC, so find view section) and try to make changes in it.
Once you done with changes, clear cache and build project again.

That might help

H Gandhi

Comment: The view I am trying to change is in the views folder of the project. I tried also to change other views, but also there nothing changes.